# Can I pass Login Creds through HTTPS to network hardware?

Tags: https, vbscript, snmp, hta

I routinely need access my subscribers radios (wireless ISP) to check or change settings.  I have made a simple script to access my Radwin radio's via an IP, but I cannot gain access to my BLiNQ radios.  Presently, in order to access the radios we need to append a suffix and prefix to the IP (**https://** 192.168.1.1 **:8080**).  From here I get directed to a security page with an error of "NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID".
I click Advanced, and then Proceed to access the login page.  Once the page loads, I can then enter a user and pass.  This is obviously extremely tedious with several hundred to go through.  The source for the device's login page is below.  Or, if anyone could point my way to decent SNMP docs on BLiNQ RevC05 and FWC-122HG-35 radios that might prove useful as well.

I currently have a rather large HTA I have built to handle all kinds of scripting fun built with VBScript, so VBScript would be helpful.  However, any scripting language I can use in an HTA where I supply the IP would be awesome.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="data:image/x-icon" type="image/x-icon">

<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/js.cookie.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-lang.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/BigInt.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/Barrett.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/RSA.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/gtk_js/languagesList.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/redirect.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.md5.js"></script>

<!-- FontAwesome Styles-->
<link href="css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">  
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="css/login.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
<!--

var multipleParameters = "en    0   3   5";

var token = multipleParameters.split("\t");
var tindex=0;
var ui_CurrentLanguage = token[tindex++];
var login_failed = parseInt(token[tindex++]);
var login_maximum_try = token[tindex++];
var login_lock_time = parseInt(token[tindex++]);

var ui_identify = "CD1E045392264A5A11462FB08674D705367905597FA4EEF4883BC2AB875F3F2F1188CA29A40906580D04897E5F3B18A8A97955E51343D40248D2AEB56E1A0CC7AC066CB165AF3392ED1E92D3915E8BC8973553EFF51A19790C319ED08005AE5F00FDEA41F3CB3F45CADDAC920BBF77CF44D5AB2D683427DA1B6F3439856A7375";
var now_page="login"

if(token[0]==undefined || token[0]==""){
    ui_CurrentLanguage='en';
}

var fun_list = fun_list || {};

/* Jeff add for parse url fun_list */

(function (func) {

    var strUrl = location.search;
    var getPara, ParaVal, getSearch;
    var aryPara = [];

    function split_url(){
         if (strUrl.indexOf("?") != -1) {
            getSearch = strUrl.split("?");
            getPara = getSearch[1].split("&");
            for (i = 0; i < getPara.length; i++) {
                ParaVal = getPara[i].split("=");
                aryPara.push(ParaVal[0]);
                aryPara[ParaVal[0]] = ParaVal[1];
            }
        }
    }
    
    function get_para(key){
        return aryPara[key];
    }
    /* execute func */
    split_url();
    
    /* export func*/
    func.get_allpara = aryPara;
    func.get_para = get_para;

}(fun_list));

function encryption(modulus,cipherobj_value)
{
        setMaxDigits(130);
        var key = new RSAKeyPair("10001", "", modulus);
        return encryptedString(key, cipherobj_value);
}

function Layout_change(){
    
    if(ui_CurrentLanguage=="ar"){
        $(".index_logo").removeClass("index_logo").addClass("index_logo_ar");

        $('div').css({
            'direction':'rtl'
        });

        $('input:text ,ul').css({
            'direction':'ltr',
            'text-align': 'right'
        });

        $('.login_btn div').css({
            'direction':'rtl'
        });
    }
}

function InitValue()
{
    get_language();
    DelAllCookie();
    $("#user_name").focus();
    
    new_action = "/cgi-bin/sysconf.cgi?page=login.asp&action=login";
    $("form").attr("action",new_action);
    $(".login_error").attr("lang","ui");

    if(fun_list.get_para("state") == "2"){
        $(".login_error").attr("lang","");
        var login_err1 = ui_lang.str("login_error1").replace("3",login_maximum_try).replace("5",login_lock_time)
        $(".login_error").html(login_err1);
        $(".login_error").show();
    }else if(fun_list.get_para("state") == "3"){
        $(".login_error").html(ui_lang.str("login_error3"));
        $(".login_error").show();
    }else if(fun_list.get_para("state") == "4"){
        $(".login_error").html(ui_lang.str("login_error2"));
        $(".login_error").show();
    }
    
    if(fun_list.get_para("state") == "0"){
        if(login_failed > 0){
            $(".login_error").html(ui_lang.str("login_error"));
            $(".login_error").show();
        }else $(".login_error").hide();
    }
    
    
    Layout_change();
}

function Validate()
{
    var old_username = $("#tmp_use_account");
    var username_val = old_username.val().replace(new RegExp(" ","g"));
    username_value=encryption(ui_identify, username_val);
    old_username.val("");
    $("#use_account").val(username_value);
    var old_password = $("#tmp_use_pd");    
    var password_val = old_password.val().replace(new RegExp(" ","g"), String.fromCharCode(31));
    password_value=encryption(ui_identify, password_val);
    old_password.val("");
    $("#use_pd").val(password_value);
    
    ui_component = add_ui_component($('form').serialize())[0];
    $("input[name=confirm_code]").before('<input type="hidden" name="ui_component" value='+ui_component+'>');
    
    $("form").submit();
}

// key enter event
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(this).keydown(function(event){
        if( event.which== 13){
            event.preventDefault();
            Validate();
        }
    });
});
    
-->
</script></head>

<body onload="InitValue();">
<div class="section">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3 text">             
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <form class="form-horizontal" data-toggle="validator" role="form" method="POST" autocomplete="off">
                <input type="hidden" name="confirm_code" value="">
                <input type="hidden" name="nosave_session_num" >
                <input type="hidden" name="use_pd" id="use_pd">
                <input type="hidden" name="use_account" id="use_account">
                <div class="banner">
                    <img src="../images/login_logo.png">            
                </div>
                <div class="form-top">
    
                </div>
                
                    <div class="form-group">
                    

                        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                            <label for="inputname" class="control-label tit" lang='ui'>login_username</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control blue" id="tmp_use_account" name="tmp_use_account" maxlength="64" lang='ui' placeholder="login_enter_username" required>
                        </div>

        
                        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                            <label for="inputPassword" class="control-label tit" lang='ui'>login_password</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                            <input type="password" class="form-control blue" id="tmp_use_pd" name="tmp_use_pd" maxlength="64" lang='ui' placeholder="login_enter_pwd">
                        </div>                              
                      
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                            <button type="button" class="btn login_btn" onclick="Validate()" lang='ui'>common_apply</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                            <div class="login_error login_fail"  style="display:none">login_error</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                        <div class="dropdown" id="dropdown_langague">
                        <button data-toggle="dropdown"  class="btn dropdown-toggle ctmbtn"> 
                            <span lang='ui'>login_language</span>
                            <span class="caret"></span>
                        </button>
                        </div> <!-- /.dropdown-alerts -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 text">             
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>   

</body></html>
```

Comment: you want to automate the login to that page? I'm not familiar with HTA but I'd approach like web scraping, I found that easy with Ruby. What do you have to do after the login?

Comment: HTA (Hypertext Application) is just a GUI way to collect scripts together inside an HMTL "App".  I've never used Ruby, and if I can get past the login I'd be happy.

Comment: something like that was the first time I used ruby also. For this it wasn't too steep. It's been years since I wrote VBscript, can't think how to approach that way. I didn't try this one, but I remember using nokogiri too and it didn't start with "I just finished bootcamp" https://itnext.io/building-a-basic-scraper-with-ruby-1cec071ada83